# Angular 5 sends tons of requests to fetch the images than expected

Tags: angular, google-chrome, https, angular-cli, angular-services

I am using `"@angular/cli": "1.6"` in a project.

I am trying to fetch the images from the server and these images can only be fetched by authorization token. So in my service, I running the following code to get the image which adds the token itself.

```
public getStudentProfilePic(url) : Observable<Blob>{
  return this.http.get<Blob>(url, {responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
}
```

In my component, I have the following code

Typescript

```
fetchStudentProfilePic(url) {
    return this.examsService.getStudentProfilePic (url).subscribe(
      res => {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL(res)
      }, 
      error => {
        this.spinnerSvc.stop();
        this.msg.push('An error occurred while downloading the file from the server', error, 'danger', 'remove')
      });
  }
```

In HTML file

```
<img src="{{fetchStudentProfilePic(stud.Student.ImageUrl)}}">
```

The problem is that I have to fetch only 27 images from the server but angular is sending a lot of requests as shown in the following image.

[image]

What is causing the angular to send a lot of requests?

More info:

Total Successfully requests: 49

Then it started with `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the way angular component change detection works. Whenever a change detection cycle is triggered, all the code in a component template is executed. Change detection will run more often than you think, [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) post explains it well.

But in summary, your problem is that you call your function inside of the template, so the function will be executed on every change detection. There are various ways to solve this, for example with pure pipes, as explained [here](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp). 
Another way is to just move your function call to the component typescript code, for example in the onInit method. There you just fetch the pictures of all students, save them in an array and then you display the contents of that array in the template.

Comment: I have created a new angular project `ng new testNgFor` then in `app` component I put `<div *ngFor="let l of [0]">
  <span>{{testtt(l)}}</span>
</div>` code and in `.ts` I added a function `testtt(l){console.log(l)}` and then i run the code and it prints 4 times `0` in console.

Comment: In a minimal example, there may be only little change detection happening. However, as you start using async operations such as events, timers or XHR (like you do with your images), the change detection is triggered more often. Read the start of this post for a simple example, analogous to yours: https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp

Comment: @Phoenix404 that is because the model in you example doesn't change. I added some bits: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bguxxp (see the console output).

Comment: so, SetInterval generates a change in component, then angular detects this change and doStuff according change?

Comment: Yes. In your case is the http call response what triggers the change detection.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `fetchStudentProfilePic` method returns a new `Subscription` object instead of an image URL.

When that method is called for every image, it triggers a http call. Once the observable is resolved, Angular change detection mechanism will update the view, calling again the method and the http call for every image and so on.

As @Tagas suggests, you should fetch the images and bind the `src` attribute to a property with the result of `window.URL.createObjectURL(res)`.